# Get product prices with multiple websites

Tags: product, magento-1.8, php, api, price

I have setup my Magento with 2 websites, with ID 1 and 4, and one store for each website.

My product has 3 prices: a Default price, and a price for each website.

How can I get these 3 prices programmatically?

See what I have tried so far:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
echo $product->getPrice() . "</br>" ;      // prints price of default website != default price
echo $product->setWebsiteId(1).getPrice() . "</br>" ; // throws exception
```

Comment: You have create store for that two website ?

Comment: Sure, I have created a store and a storeview for each website

Comment: Then Below code defiantly work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know the storeId, set in setStoreId :

```
/**
 * call the Magento catalog/product model
 * set the current store ID
 * load the product
 */
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->load($key);
```

Display in a block :

```
echo $product->getName();
echo $product->getPrice();
```

We can also use print_r to see the values :

```
print_r($product->getData());
```

The following code will show current store ID :

```
$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
```

If you change the $storeId will show different product.

Comment: You welcome :) :)

Comment: @KeyulShah do you know how to set a store id? separate question, but i think it would be useful here anyway.